# change text in QML textbox from C++ Qt 5.2.1

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm a little new to QML and C++ in general, but I'm learning quick. I'm a bit stumped on something though. I'm trying to make an application that reads text from a QML TextInput text field, and writes the data to a text area. I'm not sure what is going wrong, but upon reading the text I get the error "Unable to assign QQuickTextInput to QString" - and I'm a bit stumped on how to write back to a text area. If someone could shed some light, that would be appreciated. I've already been through the QML/C++ binding page, and that doesn't seem to help. I'm wondering if that page was written for an older version of Qt... Here's my code thus far:

QML:

```
 import QtQuick 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtWinExtras 1.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Rectangle {
    id: main
    width: 640
    height: 480
    signal onClicked_button

    TextInput {
        id: textbocks
        objectName: textbocks
        x: 280
        y: 230
        width: 80
        height: 20
        text: "Text Input"
        font.pixelSize: 12

        Button {
            id: button1
            x: -10
            y: 45
            text: "Button"
            onClicked:main.onClicked_button()
        }
    }

    TextField {
        id: textField1
        x: 257
        y: 329
        placeholderText: qsTr("Text Field")
    }
}
```

header (class - originally designed to write back to text input):

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QString>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QQmlComponent> // for accessing QML from C++
#include <QQmlContext>   // for accessing C++ from QML

class test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit test(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:

    void test_button(){
        QQuickView *view = new QQuickView(QUrl("test.qml"));
        view->show();
        QQuickItem *item = view->rootObject();

        QObject *item = object->findChild<QObject*>("textbocks");
        textbox->setProperty("text", str);

        delete textbox;
        return;}
private:
    bool switched;
    bool textOutput;
    QString str = "Hello World";
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

And main .cpp file:

```
#include "test.h"
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QObject>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QQmlComponent>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QDeclarativeEngine>
#include <QDeclarativeComponent>
#include <QDeclarativeContext>


test::test(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}


int main (int argc, char*argv[]) {


    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView(QUrl("test.qml"));
    view->show();
    QQuickItem *item = view->rootObject();

    test *funcs = new test();

    // connect button signals to their slots:
    QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(buttonClicked_button()), funcs, SLOT(test_button()));







    delete funcs;
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Some of this is still a bit abstract for me... Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

as I noticed you are creating two QQuickViews from the same QML file "test.qml" :

1.In the main function (main.cpp)

2.and in the TEST_BUTTON function (test.h)

which are different **QObject** .
Another issues are that :

- *you are assigning an object of type **TextInput** to the **objectName** property (test.qml) which is a **String***
- you are **deleting** (as Yekmen mentioned earlier) the object (**textbox (test.h) = textbocks (test.qml)**) which in the mean time you are assigning to it the string  **str="hello world"** via **setProperty()** function .
  Ahh forgot one, the **slot name** in **C++** side which must be identical to the **one declared** in **QML**

Comment: Thanks!! I was able to get it fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look this method :

```
 Connections {
 target: area
 onClicked: foo(parameters)
```

}

For example : area is your c++ object.( qmlRegisterType(myclass) )
area send a signal and after you can lauch your function. 
I think is more easy.

Comment: I'm not sure how your answer is relevant.... I'm asking about a text box, you're giving me a signal solution. I know the button works correctly, I have it working on a different test program. I just need to know why I cannot access the "text" field in a text input with the code I have...

Comment: Your objectName and your id have the same name. Sometime i have this problem when my id and my objectName have the same.

Other possibility, your "  QQuickView *view = new QQuickView(QUrl("test.qml"));" try with  QQuickView *view = new QQuickView(QUrl::fromLocalFile("test.qml"));

Comment: Why you destroy your object ?
 delete funcs;

Comment: Avoid memory overflow? Doesn't matter if I destroy it or not, I still have the same issue.